# Adding Parent Selectors To CSS block using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So we have an email builder that allows the client to create their own custom color schemes. In additon to pre-defined fields we allow them to enter their own custom CSS block to modify their color schemes.

The problem is we NEED to put a parent selector before each rule. So for instance:

```
 p {font-size:12px;}
```

will need to become

```
 .parent_selector p {font-size:12px;}
```

Is there anyway to programmatically add these parent selectors to EACH CSS rule? As an example use case let's say this is the custom css provided by the client:

```
 p {font-size:12px; font-weight:bold}
 .description {color:#cccccc; line-height:1.2em;}
 #header {padding:bottom:12px}
 .buttons .button {padding:12px; background:#112233;}
 .buttons a {text-decoration:none;}
```

I would need a parent selector before each rule. I've considered searching for brackets and adding text accordingly but it got too complicated. Another option (which I don't like) is creating a dummy selector and doing a string replace. Here is an example:

```
 .placeholder p {font-size:12px;}
```

will need to become

```
 .parent_selector p {font-size:12px;}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: jQuery provides no tools whatsoever for manipulating CSS stylesheet contents.

Comment: How were you searching for braces? It's feasible using regex. I don't really see what's wrong with the placeholder solution, if it's easier and it works then go for it

Comment: Yeah I was going to use Regex but it went over my head quick. The placeholder works but is not intuitive. It's a UX concern not a programmatic one but it's better than nothing.

Comment: You cannot manipulate the stylesheet, but you can add classes to elements that exist in the DOM using addClass. Problem is that it puts the class after the selector, not before.) Any styles you have assigned to the class, will be applied to the elements when the addClass method is applied.

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: Do you know what all of the client css rules are? I was thinking you could store them in a selector and then use jquery wrap() function to wrap them inside a new element.

Comment: @Danny Gibas I can't add classes to the elements. There can be multiple color schemes on the page and without going into detail why it's just not going to feasible. It's a fairly complex system. Good idea though. @lharby I'm not sure what you mean. We have all the CSS rules passed through a `<textarea>`. I don't know how using .wrap will work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to inject their code into something like the less preprocessor and compile before sending to the server. or create your own parser to prepend the parent selector to the classes provided. This would probably need work for the different formats that could be input by your users.

edit: on second thought don't leave it to chance. remove all double whitespace characters and you will get a consistent formatting and minification for free.

```js
function addParentSelector( parentSelector, styles ){
    return styles.replace(/((?:\s|\n|\t)+)/gm, ' ').replace(/([^{]+)({[^}]+})/gm, function(_, selectors, styles ){
        return selectors.split(',').map(function( selector ){
            return parentSelector + ' ' + selector;
        }).join(',') + styles;
    });
}

function compile(){
  var res = addParentSelector('.some-parent-selector',            document.querySelector('#styles').value );
  document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = res;
}
```

```css
/* ignore the css here */
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
}
pre {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
  word-wrap:break-word;  
}
button {
    cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 color: #fff;
 line-height: 1;
 padding: .6em .8em;
 background: #009afd;
 -webkit-transition: background 0.15s ease, color 0.15s ease;
 -moz-transition: background 0.15s ease, color 0.15s ease;
 -ms-transition: background 0.15s ease, color 0.15s ease;
 -o-transition: background 0.15s ease, color 0.15s ease;
 border: 1px solid #1777b7;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3) inset,0 1px 1px rgba(100,100,100,0.3);
 border-radius: 3px;  
}
button:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #0087de;  
}
```

```html
<textarea id='styles'>
.profile 
{
    line-height: 2;
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.profile__header { background: red; }
.profile__header-heading {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.profile__header-heading small {
    color: rgba(43,44,43,.7);
}
.profile__header-edit {
    padding: .5em 2em;
    border: .2em solid #3cf;
    color: #fff;
    background: #3cf;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .2s;
}
.profile__header-edit:hover {
    color: #3cf;
    background: #fff;
}
.profile__content p {
    color: rgba(34,35,34,.7);
    line-height: 2;
} 
</textarea>
<button onclick="compile()">click me!</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

edit: there was an issue in the Regex. I was using a [\s|\n|\t] group for space|newline|tab but it should have been a non capture group (?:\s|\n|\t).

This should be more complete. Also please be aware that `Array.prototype.map()` will fail in IE < 9.

Comment: This is awesome! Let me test it out and see how it handles various rules. I really appreciate you wiping this up.

Comment: no worries @DigitalMC hope it works for you. My test was very limited

Comment: This works wonderful. I've tested IDs, Classes, various levels of cascading as well as attribute selectors and they all work well. Thanks a million. The only thing is it doesn't work with is media queries but for my use case that doesn't matter really. I'm so grateful bud. This should be in a blog somewhere...

Comment: Also I added `.trim()` to the selector parameter in the 4th line of your code. It looks like this: `return (parentSelector + ' ' + selector.trim())`. I did this because I was getting newline characters that was breaking the rules. Other than that solid.

Comment: @DigitalMC edited the answer. there was an issue with the regex, notes above.

Comment: Awesome, I'll run some tests in the next day or so and get back with another audit. Really appreciate the effort.